# error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Router' as a type in angular 11.2

Tags: angular

I was working on upgrading an Angular 5.2 app code to Angular 11.
In this process I created a new project and ported the Angular 5.2 Code in the New App, updated the dependencies, migrated rxjs.
After that I am performing `npm install` and `ng serve` I am getting the above issue where it gives the issue:

> error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Router' as a type.

Issue is at this line:

> ```
> constructor(public router: Router) { }
> ```

My Imports:

> import { RoutesRecognized, Router } from '@angular/router';

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information for anyone to help you, sadly. Provide a reproduction on stackblitz, or at the very least provide the piece of code that throws the exception - Angular CLI will give you exact line which causes the issue.

Comment: I have rephrased the question

Comment: Are you sure the error line corresponds to the constructor's one?

Comment: Yes @JeremyThille

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the global and local typescript versions. refer https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3 for versions and install the same in local and -g(global) scope and the issue will be resolved